# Fast way to create a variable in a dataframe as a function of other variables and values in another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a first dataframe of individuals (`df_id`) that enter the data at `start_time` and exit it at `end_time`.

I have another dataframe (`df_time`) that gives me the value of a variable `x` at every point in time.

I want to create a new variable in `df_id` that will give me, for each individual, the average of `x` from the individual's start time to end time.

I was only able to do this by looping over each individual one by one, which takes a very long time. Is there a faster way to do this?

Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd 

data_id = {'id':[1, 2, 3], 'start_time':[1, 2, 4], 'end_time':[2, 4, 5]}
df_id = pd.DataFrame(data_id) 

data_time = {'time': list(range(1,6)), 'x': [2,2,4,5,3] }
df_time = pd.DataFrame(data_time) 

# This works, but is way too slow
for i, row in df_id.iterrows():
    start = row['start_time']-1
    end = row['end_time']
    df_id.at[i,'mean_x'] = ((df_time['x'][start:end])).mean()
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [apply()](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) instead of iterrows. This will cut the runtime in half

```
import pandas as pd 

df_id = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3], 'start_time':[1, 2, 4], 'end_time':[2, 4, 5]}) 
df_time = pd.DataFrame({'time': list(range(1,6)), 'x': [2,2,4,5,3]}) 

df_id['mean_x'] = df_id.apply(lambda row: df_time['x'][row['start_time']-1:row['end_time']].mean(), axis=1)
```